# Google Calendar Integration using Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, google-calendar-api

I setup Google account and enabled **`Calendar API`**. I created `OAuth2.0` authentication using `installed application` option and downloaded the `client secret` JSON file. I created a *windows form application* and manipulated the events in Google Calendar. First time it was asked access permission and it was granted, and the authentication token file created in **%AppData%** folder path. It was working fine.

But I need to create a windows service to add/update events in `Google Calendar` for different Google accounts. I am struggling here, **how to get  grant permission for any Google accounts programmatically?**

Is there any other way to do without Google access permission? I searched for samples and didn't find anything related to windows service. *`Is there any examples available to manipulate Google calendar using Windows Service?`*

**Update:**

Using `Service Account` credential:

```
String serviceAccountEmail = 
              "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory 
              + @"Configuration\" + "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.p12";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, "xxxxxxxxxx", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential
(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate)
);

// Create the service.
calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Test Calendar"
});
```

Comment: Is it your calendar?  or one owned by someone else?

Comment: There are several groups. Each group having google accounts and enabled Calendar API.

Comment: But do you personally have access to log into these accounts?  If you do using a service account may be easer then using Oauth2

Comment: I will setup with their login credentials for the first time. Using the windows service, events need to be added to appropriate google calendar.

Comment: Yes, just I tried with `Service account`. In my DB I can see the Google calendar event Id, but events not visible in Google Calendar. `Do I need to set actual email address anywhere?`

Comment: A service account is its own SUDO user identified by the service account email address.  If you granted the service account access to the calendar in question it "should" be able to update that calendar and then you will be able to see them on the website, when logged in as a normal user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81257/discussion-between-jesuraja-and-daimto).