# C#: How to use Google Calendar API in a Windows service

Tags: c#, api, google-api, windows-services, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build an application for retrieving calendar events from Google Apps Calendar.

I followed the steps on the following page which worked to a certain extend.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

The problem is, that this code doesn't work, when the application runs as a Windows service. The problem seems to be, that the code runs asynchronous and uses UserCredential. The application only works, if it is being run as a user.

Even if I manually run the application first in order to authenticate, it still doesn't work as a service.

I read somewhere, that I might be able to use ServiceAccountCredential and a public API access key. Because I have to synchronize every account (calendar) in the organization (Google Apps), this doesn't work at all. This can be done using the quickstart example, but just not as a service.

I need to be able to uthorize/synchronize using any Google Apps account, not just the one I used to create the app.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with a similar problem! Currently looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993669/google-calendar-integration-using-windows-service