# Google calendar in windows c#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I do Google account and enabled Calendar API. I created OAuth2.0 authentication in my c# windows application. I created a windows form application and manipulated the events in Google Calendar. First time it was asked access permission and it was granted, and the authentication token file created in %AppData% folder path. It was working fine.

But I need to create a windows service to add/update events in Google Calendar for different Google accounts. I am struggling here, how to get grant permission for any Google accounts programmatically?

Is there any other way to do without Google access permission? I searched for samples and didn't find anything related to windows service. Is there any examples available to manipulate Google calendar using Windows Service?

Comment: You want to add items to calendars without authenticating for those calendars?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913183/c-how-to-use-google-calendar-api-in-a-windows-service

Comment: No, I'm trying to build an application for retrieving calendar events from Google Apps Calendar.